# convert RIGHT outer join to left outer join sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, join

i need to design a query for Sqlite 
the original query was like this

```
 FROM            PhysicianActivity INNER JOIN
                     Activity ON PhysicianActivity.ActivityID = Activity.ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     PhysicianFrequency ON PhysicianActivity.PhysicianID = PhysicianFrequency.PhysicianID AND Activity.LegalEntityID = PhysicianFrequency.LegalEntityID
```

knowing that sqlite doesn't support RIGHT OUTER JOIN so i am stuck with LEFT OUTER JOIN but i can't convert this query to LEFT OUTER JOIN

can anyone help please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is RIGHT JOIN Ever Required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248246/is-right-join-ever-required)

Answer (score 2):

Most people prefer `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  The following is equivalent under most circumstances:

```
FROM  PhysicianFrequency LEFT JOIN
      PhysicianActivity 
      ON PhysicianActivity.PhysicianID = PhysicianFrequency.PhysicianID LEFT JOIN
      Activity
      ON PhysicianActivity.ActivityID = Activity.ID AND
         Activity.LegalEntityID = PhysicianFrequency.LegalEntityID
```

I would recommend that you use table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read:

```
FROM  PhysicianFrequency pf LEFT JOIN
      PhysicianActivity pa
      ON pa.PhysicianID = pf.PhysicianID LEFT JOIN
      Activity a
      ON pa.ActivityID = a.ID AND
         a.LegalEntityID = pf.LegalEntityID
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition `right outer join` will return all matching rows and the rows from the right table (the position is relative to the operator) that don't have a match.

Since you know that you want the records from the `PhysicianFrequency` table to be always available, this table should be the left table in a `left outer join`.

So, the complete statement will look something like this:

```
PhysicianFrequency left join PhysicianActivity 
on PhysicianActivity.PhysicianID = PhysicianFrequency.PhysicianID AND Activity.LegalEntityID = PhysicianFrequency.LegalEntityID
left join Activity 
on PhysicianActivity.ActivityID = Activity.ID
```