# Example where a right join cannot be converted to left join?

Tags: sql

I know that Any Right can be converted to Left Join.
But is there any example where when this thing cannot be happen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is RIGHT JOIN Ever Required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248246/is-right-join-ever-required)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you can always convert between right joins and left joins, the parsing of the SQL language can make this tricky in some cases.  For just two tables, the two forms are interchangeable.  However, for more tables, SQL parsing rules affect the outcome.  SQL parses the `from` clause from left to right, so it implicitly puts in parentheses.

For instance, it is tempting to say:

```
from a right join b right join c
```

(This is shorthand for from a right join b on . . . right join c on . . . .  I'm leaving out the `on` clauses, assuming they are in the customary places immediately following the joins.)

is the same as

```
from c left join b left join a
```

But, this is not strictly true.  One obvious difference is that the first could represent a `join` condition between `c` and `a`.  The second has trouble if that is the only condition.

The first is parsed as:

```
from (a right join b) right join c
```

This means that the first keeps all rows in `b` that don't match to a . . . and then all rows in `c` even if there are no matches in `b`.

The second:

```
from (c left join b) left join a
```

This means keep all rows in `c`, regardless of matches in `b` and `a`.

One difference is a row in `a` that matches `c` but not `b`.  In the `left join` version, the values of the `a` columns will come from `a`.  In the `right join` version, the values will be `NULL`.  Of course, this depends on the `on` clauses; the point is that there are subtle differences.

I don't like to ponder such things.  So, I basically never use `right join`.  `Left join` follows the parsing rules of SQL and it has a simple interpretation:  keep all rows in the first table regardless of matches in any of the others.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. The associativity of the joins in the absence of explicit parentheses is determined by the placement of the ON phrases and not by the order of the JOIN phrases. All your examples are messed up in consequence.

Comment: For example: `FROM a RIGHT JOIN b RIGHT JOIN c ON c.key = b.key ON b.key = a.key` is parsed with right associativity, thus making the rightmost join innermost; in contrast to your statement above.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens . . . I clarified in the answer that this syntax is a shorthand with the customary placement of the `on` clauses immediately following the joins.  SQL does associate `join` from left to right without parentheses.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: No, the ON phrases operate as a post-fix operator completely determining the associativity by ***their*** placement. You are confused by still thinking in terms of how parsing was done pre-SQL-92 standard. This is another example of why it is recommended to use the modern JOIN syntax instead of the archaic WHERE syntax for joins.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I don't see any join in the where clause in Gordon's answer (in fact there is no where clause at all in the answer)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Right; but the interpretation of SQL provided by Gordon's answer is only **correct** for pre-92 SQL joins. SQL-92 standard joins are interpreted in a vastly different manner, that in turn provides much greater processing capability, as described in *David & Fesperman*'s book linked to in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Provided only that the modern `JOIN ... ON` syntax is used exclusively, the formulation of a query with one of `LEFT` or `RIGHT` outer joins can always be reformulated using the other by simultaneously reversing the order of the subqueries on each side of the `JOIN`.

> As can be expected, the one-sided (:EFT and RIGHT) joins *are* not commutative since reversing their table arguments logically changes a LEFT `join` into a RIGHT `join` and vice versa, making the semantics and results very different. [*Advanced Standard SQL Dynamic Structured Data Modeling and Hierarchical Processing; 2013; Michael M. David & Lee Fesperman.*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=_ayRGuv7RnwC&dq=introduction%20of%20JOIN%20clause%20to%20standard%20sql&source=gbs_navlinks_s) pp 19

Comment: Maybe I don't understand this, but your answer contradicts itself. First you say "*can always be reformulated using the other*" but you quote a book that says "*are **not** commutative*" which - as far as I understand that -  means you can _not_ just flip them around.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: An operator is *commutative* when reversing the order of the operands maintains the value of the result. SO `a + b` = `b + a` but `a - b` <> `b - a`. Of course `A LEFT JOIN b` <> `b LEFT JOIN a`, by the definition of an outer join. Did you read the quite that I actually placed in my answer?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: In the pre-1992 standard, where joins **were* left associative as Gordon describes, the ambiguity of the grammar and resolution of the ambiguity through left association would create instances which were impossible to construct in a single query. The removal of ambiguity from the grammar in the 1992 standard removes this limitation.