# Convert RIGHT JOIN in LEFT JOIN

Tags: sqlite, join

I have been tasked with making queries in SQL Server stored procedures compatible with SQLite.

The following query contains `RIGHT JOIN`s, which are not compatible with SQLite:

```
SELECT ...    
FROM Operatori
INNER JOIN Preventivi
   ON Operatori.Pk = Preventivi.FkOperatori
RIGHT JOIN Operatori AS Operatori_1
INNER JOIN Soluzioni
   ON Operatori_1.Pk = Soluzioni.FkOperatore
INNER JOIN Reparti
   ON Operatori_1.FkReparto = Reparti.Pk
RIGHT JOIN Progetti
INNER JOIN Anagrafica
   ON Progetti.FkClienti = Anagrafica.Pk
   AND Soluzioni.FkProgetti = Progetti.Pk
   AND Preventivi.FkSoluzioni = Soluzioni.Pk
```

I know is that, normally, switching the tables works:

ex.

```
FROM Operatori
   RIGHT JOIN Progetti
```

became:

```
FROM Progetti
   LEFT JOIN Reparti
```

But how can I do the conversion if I have other `JOIN`s in the same query?

Comment: What's the original database? `RIGHT JOIN` is normally accompanied by a condition just like `LEFT JOIN` is... The two are supposed to be equivalent, just in the reverse order. `RIGHT JOIN` without a condition looks like some database specific extension of SQL.

Comment: @jpmc26 It was a stored Procedure inside SQLServer, unfortunately i can't provide more information about it because i'm new to this job and i didn't created the stored procedure. And the one that did it is not here anymore. :(

Comment: I've made some clarifications. Please check over and make sure I didn't change your intent.

Comment: @jpmc26 Thank you, sorry for the bad english :D

Comment: I think your bigger problem is not the `RIGHT JOIN`s themselves as much as it is that the `RIGHT JOIN`s don't have a condition, so they might be equivalent to `FULL JOIN`. But I'd have to look up the relevant SQL Server docs to be sure.

Comment: @jpmc26 As far as I know the programmer behind this could also be bad

Comment: Has the query been tested? Is it in use in production? If it works, you probably want to mimic its behavior. If you're not sure of that, find out the requirements and make sure it's currently behaving as needed.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, it has been used for years in the company's main program

Comment: Is this the exact query? Did you remove any parentheses?

Comment: @CL. No, is the exact query, i've only omitted what is after SELECT because i didn't think it was important

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is RIGHT JOIN Ever Required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248246/is-right-join-ever-required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compared to an inner join, an outer join returns additional result rows for table rows without a match.
However, this applies only to the matching done with that join's ON clause.
So this query does not actually have any outer joins that make sense, because

- the two right joins do not have an ON clause, so there are no matches that could be handled specially; and
- even if there were ON clauses on the two outer joins, they are followed by inner joins on the matched columns, so any rows with NULLs in those columns would be filtered out by the inner joins.

So in this query, you can simply replace RIGHT with INNER (in both databases), and the result is guaranteed to be the same.